# How to create a 3d graph of grid seach

Tags: plotly, grid-search, hyperparameters

I'm working on a random forest regressor.
I used GridSearch and tuned hyperparameters (max_features, n_estimators, max_depth).
I created results Dataframe from the attribute cv_results_

`**results = pd.DataFrame(grid_search.cv_results_)

results = results[['param_max_features', 'param_n_estimators', 'param_max_depth', 'mean_test_score']]

results.columns = ['max_features', 'n_estimators', 'max_depth', 'mean_test_score']**`

This is what the DataFrame looks like:
[image]
Now I would create an interactive surface plot (if possible with plotly) to explain how the model performance changes when the parameters change, but I don't know how to do this (4 columns in df but in graph required 3).
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you show a sample of the `results` DataFrame, and any code you have tried to create the surface plot in plotly? This will help make your question more reproducible so that people can help figure out an answer for you

Comment: I tried to show the screenshot of the graph and the dataframe. I hope you can see the images

Comment: Please include properly formatted code in your question. The screenshot of your notebook is visible, but people would have to type out your code line by line to reproduce your issue and it would be much easier to be able to just copy and paste what you have done so we can diagnose your problem. You can read a bit more about creating an minimal reproducible example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your problem is well-defined as it is unclear how you can create a surface plot from your data. If you were performing a grid search over two variables, then you could create a surface plot using the mean_test_score as your z-value since the grid search would be occurring over your x- and y-values. However, since you are performing a grid search over three variables, if you make the z-value any one of these variables, there will be multiple z-values corresponding to each x- and y-value, resulting in a closed rectangular prism.

What you could do instead is make a scatter plot where the markers change color based on the `mean_test_score` value. The color scale bar would allow the user to see what combination of hyperparameters maximizes the mean test score.

I recreated some data that I imagine looks like your `results` gridsearch DataFrame with discrete values for each of the hyperparameter columns, and a range of mean test scores similar to yours. In the attached image, the cursor is hovering over the combination of hyperparameters corresponding to the one of the best mean test scores.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

## recreate a DataFrame that looks how a gridsearch would look
features = list(range(1,7))
estimators = [25,50,75,100,125,150,175,200]
depth = list(range(1,6))
grid = []
for x in features:
    for y in estimators:
        for z in depth:
            grid.append([x,y,z])
results = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array(grid), columns=["max_features","n_estimators","max_depth"])

## let's assume your mean_test_score gradually increases with some noise 
np.random.seed(42)
mean_scores = np.linspace(0.17, 0.42, len(results)) + np.random.normal(0, 0.01, len(results))
results["mean_scores"] = mean_scores

fig = px.scatter_3d(results, x='max_features', y='n_estimators', z='max_depth', color='mean_scores')
fig.update_layout(
    title="Hyperparameter tuning",
    autosize=True, width=700, height=700,
    margin = dict(l=65, r=50, b=65, t=90))
fig.show()
```

[image]